# automated docker build run error: Unable to find image

Tags: build, automation, docker

I have an automated docker build set up and the build appears to be working fine but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
  Unable to find image 'dtwill/ddcintegrationdevenvs:blkmesa_esrbtmq' locally
  Pulling repository dtwill/ddcintegrationdevenvs
  2014/09/11 14:33:20 Error: image dtwill/ddcintegrationdevenvs not found
```

Run command:

```
  docker run -i -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -p 9001:9001 -p 15672:15672 --rm -t dtwill/ddcintegrationdevenvs:blkmesa_esrbtmq
```

I'm trying to test:

a. docker looks for image locally
  b. if image is not found locally that docker will successfully pull and run image

Image is valid `https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dtwill/ddcintegrationdevenvs/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image you linked to is private. Did you do a `docker login` or create a [.dockercfg file](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/bbf644ed62cf815cf40ef3de3345fac7ed42588a/docs/sources/use/workingwithrepository.rst#authentication-file) before `docker run`?

(BTW, I linked to an outdated commit in the docker source repo for the authentication file since it seems to be broken in the current documentation.)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made the build private and the git repo is private as well to mimic the would-be scenario. I was/am logged in. I wanted to also test if someone else (not logged in) could run the image. I'm unsure of the level of "protection" the private build switch has. As a company, the images will most likely be private since they will contain sensitive config settings that need to remain private. It is working now (no changes made). Hmmm??? Thank you for the tips and the link!!!

Comment: I am unsure now what was the issue....if it was the docker registry that was down or some other network related issue.