# Docker (under boot2docker) does not look for/find local images when building

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm running Docker on OS X under boot2docker 1.3.1

I built myself an image, `oceania/python`:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
oceania/python      0.1                 800229a896ff        16 hours ago        510.4 MB
```

I have another Dockerfile now where I want to use `FROM oceania/python`

When I try to build this image I get:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 31.74 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM oceania/python
Pulling repository oceania/python
2014/11/20 17:23:51 Error: image oceania/python not found
```

Shouldn't it look at my local images first before going online to try and pull it?

Am I really obliged to upload it to a repository?

@jpetazzo answers here that what I am doing should work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20501690/202168

I assume the problem may therefore be boot2docker related

Answer (score 3):

Uhhh, ok...

It seems I have to include the tag, i.e.

```
FROM oceania/python:0.1
```

...then it works.

[The docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) appear to allow a `FROM` directive without the tag, and they say: *"If no tag is given to the FROM instruction, latest is assumed."*

I guess the underlying problem is that if your image is not uploaded to an index somewhere then it can't resolve 'latest' to a tag.

Another thing that's confusing is it seems in other people's answers and comments on similar issue, eg [automated docker build run error: Unable to find image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25790479/202168) they get some output that looks like:

```
Unable to find image 'foo/bar:baz' locally
```

but in my output there's nothing to say docker even tried to look locally

Comment: It isn't that `latest` resolves to a tag, `latest` IS a tag. You can have multiple tags for the same image ID. I'd recommend building `oceania/python` without the `:0.1` and then tagging the resulting image ID with something like `docker tag oceania/python oceania/python:0.1`.

Comment: Do you mean you have to manually tag an image as 'latest' ? Or that docket doesn't know to auto tag an image as latest unless you first build without tag? Seems odd behavior either way

Comment: Correct, if you build image without a tag, it uses `latest` as the tag. You can also just manually tag as latest.